# A riddle fit for Friday

Tags: riddle

1. My first part sometimes marches, sometimes crawls, sometimes passes, but always seems to keep going.
2. My second part is just past the loneliest. That is before both of *you* left that part.
3. My third is something pretty common. It shows up around birthdays and some holidays and when people leave a place for good.

**What am I?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you

> **Time to party**?
>  1. **Time** marches on, crawls, and passes.
>  2. One is the loneliest number, and just past one is two. Two - w ('both of you' = 'double U' = w) is **to**.
>  3. Birthday party, holiday party, retirement / going-away party